# pygsheets.authorize() вызывает FileNotFoundError при записи cache-файла на Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pygsheets

Код:

```
import pygsheets

sheet = pygsheets.authorize(service_file='service_creds.json')
sh = sheet.create('my-sheet')
sh = sheet.open('my-sheet')
print(sh.id)
wks = sh.sheet1
wks.update_cell('A2', "!!!Help")
wks.update_cells('A2', "HELP")
sh.share("ХХХХХХХХХ@gmail.com")
```

Выдает ошибку:

> `Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\Users\beast\Desktop\lllkkk.py", line 3, in <module>
>           sheet = pygsheets.authorize(service_file='service_creds.json')
>         File "C:\Users\beast\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pygsheets\client.py",
>   line 552, in authorize
>           rclient = Client(oauth=credentials, **client_kwargs)
>         File "C:\Users\beast\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pygsheets\client.py",
>   line 79, in __init__
>           self._fetch_sheets()
>         File "C:\Users\beast\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pygsheets\client.py",
>   line 92, in _fetch_sheets
>           results = self._execute_request(None, request, False)
>         File "C:\Users\beast\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pygsheets\client.py",
>   line 418, in _execute_request
>           response = request.execute()
>         File "C:\Users\beast\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\_helpers.py",
>   line 133, in positional_wrapper
>           return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
>         File "C:\Users\beast\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py",
>   line 839, in execute
>           method=str(self.method), body=self.body, headers=self.headers)
>         File "C:\Users\beast\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py",
>   line 166, in _retry_request
>           resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
>         File "C:\Users\beast\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\transport.py",
>   line 175, in new_request
>           redirections, connection_type)
>         File "C:\Users\beast\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\transport.py",
>   line 282, in request
>           connection_type=connection_type)
>         File "C:\Users\beast\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py",
>   line 1322, in request
>           (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
>         File "C:\Users\beast\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py",
>   line 1132, in _request
>           _updateCache(headers, response, content, self.cache, cachekey)
>         File "C:\Users\beast\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py",
>   line 403, in _updateCache
>           cache.set(cachekey, text)
>         File "C:\Users\beast\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py",
>   line 690, in set
>           f = open(cacheFullPath, "wb")
>       FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\beast\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\32c31633-19f0-4dd3-930c-b23224e97eea\\www.googleapis.com,drive,v3,files,corpora=user&pageSize=500&fields=files%28id%2C+name%29&q=mimeType%3D%27application%2Fvnd.google-apps.spreadsheet%27&supportsTeamDrives=false&includeTeamDriveItems=fal,6fa737f4e6c871f0b9ea9ea38467b8b6'`

Исправляю код:

```
import pygsheets

sheet = pygsheets.authorize(service_file='service_creds.json',no_cache=True)

sh = sheet.open('my-sheet')
print(sh.id)
wks = sh.sheet1
wks.update_cell('A2', "!!!Help")
wks.update_cells('A2', "HELP")
sh.share("ХХХХХХХХХ@gmail.com")
```

И как это далее исправить ?

> `Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\beast\Desktop\lllkkk.py", line 9, in <module>
>       wks.update_cells('A2', "HELP")   File "C:\Users\beast\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pygsheets\worksheet.py",
>   line 431, in update_cells
>       self.client.sh_update_range(self.spreadsheet.id, body, self.spreadsheet.batch_mode, parse=parse)   File
>   "C:\Users\beast\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pygsheets\client.py",
>   line 352, in sh_update_range
>       self._execute_request(spreadsheet_id, final_request, batch)   File "C:\Users\beast\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pygsheets\client.py",
>   line 418, in _execute_request
>       response = request.execute()   File "C:\Users\beast\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\_helpers.py",
>   line 133, in positional_wrapper
>       return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\beast\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py",
>   line 844, in execute
>       raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri) googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting
>   https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1eptzus7Xl-pF0blTrxSPQ-DH_VlQARSJwILgu0oFpYU/values/Sheet1%21A2%3AB6?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED&alt=json
>   returned "Invalid value at 'data.values'
>   (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue), "HELP"">`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\beast\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\feb4faff-e992-43b6-997d-577799ff725f\\www.googleapis.com,drive,v3,files,corpora=user&pageSize=500&fields=files%28id%2C+name%29&q=mimeType%3D%27application%2Fvnd.google-apps.spreadsheet%27&supportsTeamDrives=false&includeTeamDriveItems=fal,6fa737f4e6c871f0b9ea9ea38467b8b6'

Comment: добавьте ошибку в вопрос.

Comment: related: [httplib2 cache file name problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35075919/4279)

Comment: @МиколаСухецький, это уже другой вопрос - [задайте новый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)...

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте отключить кеш ([здесь](https://github.com/nithinmurali/pygsheets/issues/100) описание проблемы):

```
sheet = pygsheets.authorize(service_file='service_creds.json', no_cache=True)
```

Этот баг уже исправлен на [GitHub](https://github.com/nithinmurali/pygsheets)

[По совету @jfs можно попробовать установить `staging` версию:](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/780723/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-python-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-filenotfounderror/780745#comment1224223_780745)

```
pip install -U git+https://github.com/nithinmurali/pygsheets.git@staging
```

Comment: вместо monkey-patch, можно со staging ветки установить попробовать: `pip install -U git+https://github.com/nithinmurali/pygsheets.git@staging`

Comment: @jfs, спасибо - добавил в ответ